# How to deserialize json object with an internal object to a single java object by using google gson library?

Tags: json, gson

I have the following json file:

```
{
  "sqldb": [
    {
      "name": "mydb",
      "label": "sqldb",
      "plan": "sqldb_free",
      "credentials": {
        "port": 50000,
        "db": "SQLDB",
        "username": "xxxxxxx",
        "host": "75.126.155.92",
        "hostname": "75.126.155.92",
        "jdbcurl": "jdbc:db2://75.126.155.92:50000/SQLDB",
        "uri": "db2://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@75.126.155.92:50000/SQLDB",
        "password": "xxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The object has following structure: list of `sqldb` objects, which has internal `credentials` object. How can I parse it by [Google Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson) into single `sqldb` object? I mean is it possible to create by using gson's annotations, *Java Object* like following:

```
public class VcapObject{
    private String name;
    private String label;
    private String plan;
    private String port;
    private String db;
    private String username;
    private String host;
    private String hostname;
    private String jdbcurl;
    private String uri;
    private String password;
}
```

which will be filled by:

```
 VcapObject vcapObject = gson.fromJson(vcapString, VcapObject.class);
```

for example?

Comment: Is it possible to modify your json as you need to set this in plan structure as your class VcapObject? Just like ---- {"name":"mydb","label":"sqldb","plan":"sqldb_free","port":50000,"db":"SQLDB","username":"xxxxxxx","host":"75.126.155.92","hostname":"75.126.155.92","jdbcurl":"jdbc:db2://75.126.155.92:50000/SQLDB","uri":"db2://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@75.126.155.92:50000/SQLDB","password":"xxxxxxx"}

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the internal `credentials` object, you need a custom [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) that copies the fields from the inner class to the outer class.  There are a few different strategies you could take, but here is one that modifies the JSON tree and feeds it back to Gson.

```
public class VcapDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<VcapObject> {

    private static final String MERGE_FIELD = "credentials";
    final private Gson gson;

    public VcapDeserializer() {
        gson = new Gson();
    }

    @Override
    public VcapObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if(json.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
            if(jsonObject.has(MERGE_FIELD)) {
                // We have the object, get all the fields
                JsonObject mergeObject = jsonObject.get(MERGE_FIELD).getAsJsonObject();
                Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = mergeObject.entrySet();
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
                    // Copy property to top level object
                    jsonObject.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                }
                // now that we have copied the fields, remove the nested object
                jsonObject.remove(MERGE_FIELD);
            }
            // Deserialize the top-level object
            return gson.fromJson(jsonObject, VcapObject.class);
         } else {
            // top level is supposed to be an object
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then create a custom `Gson` instance with `GsonBuilder` --

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(VcapObject.class, new VcapDeserializer()).create();
```

Note -- from your question it is unclear if you want to get rid of the top-level wrapper object.  I assumed not because you did not say the array was always going to return one element. So you will still need that --

```
public class SqlDbWrapper {
    List<VcapObject> sqldb;
}
```

and then deserialize with --

```
    SqlDbWrapper sqlDbWrapper = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SqlDbWrapper.class);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make a wrapper class containing a Collection of VcapObject, for example VcapList. Then you can pass VcapList as class to fromJson. Add a method to VcapList to get the first if not empty.

Comment: You didn't understand me, I'd like to get rid of internal object `credentials`, fill all parameters in a single object `VcapObject`. It doesn't disturb me to store collection of `VcapObject` objects in a `List`